# How Can I Get My Chickens to Integrate Into One Flock?

Tags: chickens

Our flock has been through a lot of changes. We lost two of our oldest birds in late winter. This left us with 1 chicken and chickens don't like to be alone. We bought two pullets, separated the run beneath the coop in half for a couple weeks with grating, so they could see each other and not be aggressive.

Flash forward, we are still trying to build our flock and purchased two more pullets. My husband threw away the grating in the meantime and so we've divided the two groups up (the 3 big girls and the 2 pullets) in such a way as they can't see each other.

Currently, I'm trying to get them to mix and mingle in the yard, outside the coop to get used to each other, but the big girls chase the little girls together and the little girls run away and stick together like glue.

How do I get all my chickens to flock together happily?